# Login failed using vtwsclib

Tags: php, vtiger

I can't log in my app using vtwsclib library function `doLogin()`.
I would like retrieve some data from crm via the web services but I keep getting "*login failed*" message.

Beside that, I got no errors or warning from php.

My system is a xampp localhost, php -v 7.1.33.

Do I have to make some changes within the library code in addition of the code here below?

```
$url = 'urlofmyvtecrmaccess';the url to my crm access page.

$client = new Vtiger_WSClient($url);

$login = $client->doLogin('mycrmuser', 'mywebserviceaccesskey');

if (!$login) 

    echo 'Login Failed';

else 

    echo 'Login Successful';
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you provide full url to the webservice file ?

Like http://yourcrm.com/webservice.php

You could find if there is any error in the api call using
$client->lastError() method

You can also debug inside doLogin() method to identifiy the error

Check the api response if it has any information of error

Answer (score 0):

You must have to pass your encrypted password and for encryption, you have to use md5.

```
$encryptedPassword = md5('useraccesskey');
$login = $client->doLogin('mycrmuser', $encryptedPassword);
```